# How to add a page with url suffix or extension?

Tags: url

I am using squarespace templates to establish website.

I am wondering whether I can create and add a page with 'txt' suffix？

for example, my website is: https://www.hello.com

I want to add a page with url as: https://www.hello.com/yy.txt, the page is not a file for downloading, but an html using  tag to show txt characters.

a bit like this website: https://outfit7.com/app-ads.txt

Comment: Web site builders typically do not allow you to add custom content types or control the server content-type mappings; but a quick workaround might be to embed your HTML content in `<pre>`...`</pre>` tags to have it displayed verbatim as plain unformatted text.

Comment: add can I create the page with txt suffix url? using cloudflare?